# Good problems to do while reading Hardy's book on divergent series?

Tags: reference-request, divergent-series

I am reading Hardy's text on divergent series and to my great dissapointment it has no exercises. I wonder if anybody among you know of some suitable references with problems to read simultaneously with Hardy's book.

Comment: There are some exercises in Bromwich's treatment in the 1908 1st edition of his **An Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series** -- see [here](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoth00bromuoft) or [here](https://archive.org/details/anintroductiont00bromgoog). Incidentally, much of this material was omitted in the 1925 2nd edition, so you specifically want to look at the 1908 1st edition.

Comment: you can also search on this forum [all the discussion tagged 'divergent-series'](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergent-series) I bet you'll find much more than in any book on the subject

Comment: Konrad Knopp in his book on series has a chapter about divergent series (chap 13 in the german edition) and has many exercises. (Don't have the exact english title at hand, but the book has been at least partially readable via google-books some years ago)

Comment: I have had a quick look at Bromwich's 1st and 2nd edition and find that the 1st is clearer and more concise.